# issue when two SurfaceViews are created in relativelayout for android Kitkat

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

When i am trying to create two surfaceviews in one relative layout, one for local preview frame and other for remoteview, i am not able to see my local preview frames. Complete screen is used by remote view. It works fine for jellybean and below versions but does not work on kitkat.(I am working on a VideoCall application over IP)
Here is the code snippet i am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/root_layout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#FFFFFF">
   <SurfaceView
     android:id="@+id/remote_surface"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
   /> 
   <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/local_surface"
    android:layout_height="180px"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/swap_camera"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border" 
  /> 
</Relativelayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set the width of `remote_surface` to `fill_parent` so it is essentially covering the `local_surface` view. Put the line `android:layout_above="@id/local_surface"`. That should work.

Comment: After doing this, remote_surface is not covering the full screen, it is leaving the complete width of screen instead of 180Px for local_surface